# Why the difference in the number of views?

Tags: discussion, views

I have often noticed that some people have questions which have, like some 4k views in 10 minutes while my questions have ~100. Same tags, diferent questions.

Not that it matters a lot, but it does matter (affects the chances of some person good at it answering my question).

Why the HUGE difference?

Comment: 4k views in 10 minutes? Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to add commonly googled keywords to that list.

I asked a question on superuser about a windows 7 driver for a common video card  & it seems to have racked up 1k views very quickly,  being  the [3rd site on google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=windows+7+driver+82865G) probably helps!

Comment: With time, the view count becomes almost meaningless. I just got a silver badge for a question that I closed 38 minutes after posting.

Answer (score 4):

You could be looking at the active page (the https://stackoverflow.com/ home page), which shows all items that have recently been either added/edited/answered.  This will show updates for old items as well as newly posted questions.  On this page, a very popular question (ie, the 4K views) can sit next to a newly posted item.

If you are interested in seeing the view-count activity on new posts only, you can click on the 'Questions' tab (https://stackoverflow.com/questions) at the top of the page, and then on the 'newest' subtab.  With this filter, you will see items in a submitted order (most recent on top).

Answer (score 3):

Potential reasons in view discrepancies (although I think your anecdote is extremely unreliable as evidence):

- Time of the day can be an important factor in how many views a question gets.
- The quality of the question, or how controversial the question may be
- The person asking it. Since we can follow users, it could stand to reason that someone with more "star power" like a Jeff Atwood or a Jon Skeet would attract loads more attention than a less well known counterpart.